# Unable to install grpcio using pip install grpcio==1.18.0

Tags: python, pip, grpc, yolo, yolov5

I am getting errors while installing `yolox` on my win10 machine. I have upgraded `pip` and `installtools`. It does not help.

When I use `pip install grpcio==1.18.0` I get an error,
while `pip install grpcio` works well.

But it seems `onnx==1.8.1` needs the verified version at 1.18.0? I don't know...

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Knight\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac7tlzg1\grpcio_bb43f1f19b054e8f975f746e324f1077\src\python\grpcio\commands.py", line 272, in build_extensions
      build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\Yolox_py3.9_offical\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\Yolox_py3.9_offical\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\Yolox_py3.9_offical\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\Yolox_py3.9_offical\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
      objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
    File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\Yolox_py3.9_offical\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 407, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

Note that this error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
Running setup.py clean for grpcio
Failed to build grpcio
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade pip, update setuptools and then install the grpcio module.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install --no-cache-dir grpcio
```

The version can be changed.